# Setting up a Zooming UIScrollView with a UIImageView

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to setup a UIScrollView subclass that loads a UIImageView and a UIImage within it. The image should be zoomable (by pinch) following the apple docs here- https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html

I have created a subclass of UIScrollView which completes the following:

```
@interface SPMScrollView () {}

@property (nonatomic) float zoomedInScale;

@property (nonatomic) float naturalZoomScale;

@end

@implementation SPMScrollView

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        super.delegate = self;

        self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
        self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self addSubview:self.imageView];

    }
    return self;
}


-(void)setupScales {
    self.maximumZoomScale = 2.0f;
    self.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
}


-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.imageView.image = image;
            self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width / 2, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
            [self setupScales];
        });

    NSLog(@"The image frame is: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.imageView.frame));

}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate methods
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}
```

On load the View Controller simply completes the following:

```
_scrollView.contentSize=self.view.frame.size;
[_scrollView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WeCanDoIt"]];
```

The issue I have is that the image is not actually correctly loaded in the first place/load. Even thought the contentMode on the Image view is being set when it is created the image shows like this initially.

[image]

Can anyone assist on why this may not be working as expected please?

This is a full screenshot:
[image]
There should be some white space at the bottom (which is the actual image) but off screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with IOS7 only. The issue was that the origin.y was not being set correctly and the center was not correct.

After a while of testing I found the issue was due to the automatic scroll insets being created:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets)]) {
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

The above resolves the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

you set the contentMode to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` there should be some black borders in the upper and bottom if the UIImageView frame's ratio is not the same with the image. you can set `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` to see whether the UIImageView is correct, but this time the image is stretched not by the ratio.

Comment: Please see the edit above, I have added a full screenshot. Yes I would expect black at the top/bottom if the image did fit. But the image is not actually completely on screen, there should be some more white at the bottom of the image and fit the screen.

Comment: The screenshot does not completely show but the end of the simulator is where the image ends.

Comment: have you tried to print out the frame of the UIImageView?why don't use `self.bounds` (instead of `self.frame`) to init it?

Comment: It makes no difference, I think the issue is that the navigation bar is hidden but still seen as there? in some way.

Comment: are you pushing the viewcontroller to show the view? if so, maybe the UINavigationbar